# Oracle varchar2 and unicode texts

Tags: sql, oracle, unicode, varchar, varchar2

[According to spec](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-varchar2/) `VARCHAR2(max_size CHAR)` should store `max_size` chars. I observe other/strange behavior for Unicode texts.

Let's consider that example:

```
create table test (id varchar2(3 char) not null, primary key (id));

insert into test(id) values('abc');
insert into test(id) values('ффф');

Query 1 ERROR: ORA-12899: value too large for column "TEST"."TEST"."ID" (actual: 6, maximum: 3)
```

So varchar2 3 chars actually mean the same as byte? **NO :)**

```
create table test (id varchar2(3 byte) not null, primary key (id))

insert into test(id) values('abc')
insert into test(id) values('ффф')

Query 1 ERROR: ORA-12899: value too large for column "TEST"."TEST"."ID" (actual: 18, maximum: 3)
```

**And my question remains how to tell Oracle that varchar2 length is for Unicode text (UTF8 to be more precise)?**

**Update:** Is it possible to write down a SQL query that will show all tables/columns that length was in bytes?

Actually, my issue split into 2 parts incorrect query encoding of TablePlus, length in bytes (w/o char suffix) for random columns :)

**Update 2:** Thanks to @Wernfried Domscheit!

The query show table and columns with `varchar2` that length is provided in `byte`s:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_LENGTH, CHAR_USED
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR2' AND CHAR_USED = 'B'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is working for me:

```
SELECT * 
FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS 
WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

PARAMETER          VALUE      
------------------------------
NLS_CHARACTERSET   AL32UTF8   

1 row selected.



CREATE TABLE TEST (ID VARCHAR2(3 CHAR));
Table created.

INSERT INTO TEST(ID) VALUES('abc');
1 row created.

INSERT INTO TEST(ID) VALUES('ффф');
1 row created.
```

Maybe a typo on your side?

**Update:**

Looks like your client uses wrong character settings.

ф ([U+0444: Cyrillic Small Letter Ef](https://unicode-table.com/en/0444/)) has these byte values:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Encoding|hex        |dec (bytes)|dec       |binary                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|UTF-8   |D1 84      |209 132    |53636     |11010001 10000100                  |
|UTF-16BE|04 44      |4 68       |1092      |00000100 01000100                  |
|UTF-16LE|44 04      |68 4       |17412     |01000100 00000100                  |
|UTF-32BE|00 00 04 44|0 0 4 68   |1092      |00000000 00000000 00000100 01000100|
|UTF-32LE|44 04 00 00|68 4 0 0   |1141112832|01000100 00000100 00000000 00000000|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`DUMP` should return `Typ=1 Len=6 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: d1,84,d1,84,d1,84` but you get `ef,bf,bd` which is [U+FFFD: Replacement Character](https://unicode-table.com/en/FFFD/)

You don't insert `ффф`, it is converted to `���`.

I guess actually your client uses UTF-8 but you did not tell the database, so most likely the database assumes the client uses default `US7ASCII` (or something else). The client sends 6 Bytes (`d1,84,d1,84,d1,84`) but the Oracle database interprets it as 6 Single-Byte characters.

Typically you use the `NLS_LANG` environment variable to define this. However, dbeaver is Java based and Java/JDBC does not use the `NLS_LANG` settings - at least not by default.

Comment: Nope.
SELECT * 
FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS 
WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'

NLS_CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8

Can that behavior be bound to Oracle version/edition?

Comment: Rechecked with your SQL (copy-paste to console + drop existed test table). The same error. My database version is "Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production"

Comment: Which tool do you use? Try `INSERT INTO TEST(ID) VALUES('ф')` and check with `DUMP()` what was actually inserted.

Comment: TablePlus, dbeaver or Oracle jdbc (thin) Java driver

Comment: What do you get from `SELECT DUMP(ID, 1016) FROM TEST;`?

Comment: Typ=1 Len=6 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: ef,bf,bd,ef,bf,bd

Comment: You're right! It's TWO different issues: TablePlus incorrectly set query encoding. Some columns were provided without char notation (i.e. were in bytes!)

Is it possible to write a script that shows all table/columns where varchar length is in bytes?

Comment: Yes, try `SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_LENGTH, CHAR_USED FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR2' AND CHAR_USED = 'B'` Also when you don't specify either `BYTE` or `CHAR` then the default is given by session parameter `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS`